# how to upload files to server through c#.net?

Tags: c#-4.0

I m trying to upload images,audio files and videos to server through C#.net.
What are the ways I can do that?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints would be a good start

Comment: How do you want to upload? File share? FTP?

Comment: i want to upload through FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a windows client application? ASP Forms? MVC?

**EDIT**: Then use the File Upload control.

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/use-fileupload-ctrl-asp4-cs.aspx

Comment: See EDIT: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/use-fileupload-ctrl-asp4-cs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246